# Why are some EIPs specified in "params" and others in "engine"-->"params

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, genesis

I see that in the main net Parity chain spec file (https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/ethcore/res/ethereum/foundation.json) some eipTransitions are specified in the engine-->Ethash-->params section and other are specified in the params section.

Why is this?  Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. All parameters in engine > ethash > params are only applicable to the Ethash engine, all other parameters are shared with other engines.

Comment: You said that it doesn't matter but "gasLimitBoundDivisor" throws an error with Parity 1.7.9 if it is in the "engine" section.  Is that a Parity bug?

Comment: That's why we moved it in 1.8.0.

Comment: To be clear, which section does it belong in as of Parity 1.8.0+?

Comment: Move registrar, gasLimitBoundDivisor, and eip155Transition from engine (Ethash/AuthorityRound/etc.) to general params section. See [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/594716dc1ec822feb0230c4d57e99c4810e4b813/CHANGELOG.md#parity-v180-2017-10-15).